# gobject-introspection install failure, not build

Tags: gobject-introspection

I am trying to install gobject-introduction in mac M1 using homebrew, but it will occur the following errors. I can not find relevant solution for it. Does any one have experience on it why i can not install gobject-introspection?

[image]